# Vhosts not working on Linux Server

Tags: server, apache2, dns, virtualhost, apache2.4

A few weeks ago I installed LAMP on Linux Server(Version 4.4.0-24).
Apache(Version 2.4.20) works fine and I can access my Apache2 Debian Default Page on `192.168.10.129`. Now I want to create virtual hosts so I can start developing.
But that is the point where it goes wrong.. I cant access them..
When I go to my virtual host site1.example.com my browser says This site is not accessible and DNS not found.

My Files:

**site1.example.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@site1.example.com
    ServerName site1.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.example.com/httpdocs

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I enabled this virtual host with `sudo a2enssite site1.example.com.conf` and reloaded apache. What pretty wierd is when I replace `*80` with `192.168.10.129` it works but I can't access the ServerName..

**etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 developmentserver

::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

The DNS is not set for site1.example.com at the moment but I've tried it but no results..

Before marking this question as duplicated.
I've searched around this forum and other sites for weeks and tried a lot but nothing helped me out.

```
  - Set DNS in hosts 
  - Many Virual hosts builds
  - Many tutorials
```

Unfortunately I get no error I can show

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set the DNS records on your domain manager to point to your IP address? Subdomains need specific records unless you have a `*.domain.com` record.

Comment: @Zacharee1 
Where can I set up DNS records?

Comment: Go to your domain registrar's website and log in?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I'm just trying to get someting like this tutorial working: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts I have no Domain registar website.

Comment: Then how do you have a domain?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Oh, Its an Apache2 installation on my PC in VM Ware. Now I'm trying to create virtual hosts but that isn't working. I have no "Real" domain

Comment: So what are you connecting to? An IP? They don't have subdomains.

Comment: I dont think we understand each ohter ;)

Comment: @Zacharee1 This is exactly what I want and what I'm trying. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: Can I please have whatever you are connecting to? Are you connecting to, say, 192.168.254.45, or are you connecting to something.com?

Comment: I'm connecting to 192.168.10.129 that the local IP from my Linux installation. http://prntscr.com/bmsd5g

Comment: Read my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said in the comments you're using an IP address to connect. IP addresses don't have subdomains since they aren't domains in the first place.

`http://example.192.168.0.1` treats `example.192.168` as the subdomain and `0.1` as the actual domain. `example.192.168.0.1` will just search that text if you have an omnibar like Chrome.

If you want subdomains and virtual hosts, you need an actual domain. There are free options out there, like [Dot TK](http://dot.tk) (Now Freenom). Register something there, then set up CloudFlare to have better DNS management.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought it was possible to run Apache2 on linux server and create vhost like in WAMP but thats something else I think. I know IP address can't have sub domain. I thought the IP address was just like localhost in WAMP

Comment: You can do virtual hosts, just not with IP addresses.

Comment: Sorry , I thought it could

Comment: Like I said in my answer, IP addresses don't have subdomains. I should say, you can do virtual hosts with IPs, but only if you have different IPs for the same computer.